# How to use ui-sref in nested Angular UI router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, ui-sref

Its has been a heavy hours research and applying the techniques however I am not able to solve the issue. My app has three top navigations which are home, sports and country.

```
<head>
<script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
```

The navigation looks like:
HTML looks like below which is in index.html

```
<ul> 
    <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="sports">Sports</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="country">Country</a></li>
</ul>
<div ui-view></div>
```

In sports.html, there are other three navigation, which are not working (they are not even clickable).

```
<ul> 
    <li><a ui-sref="sports.football">Football</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="sports.weightlifting">Weightlifting</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="sports.swimming">Swimming</a></li>
</ul>
<div ui-view></div>
```

Angular looks like

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
url: '/', 
templateUrl: 'index.html'      
})
.state('sports', {
url: '/sports', 
templateUrl: 'sports.html'      
})    
.state('country', {
url: '/country', 
templateUrl: 'country.html'      
})
.state('sports.football', {
url: '/football', 
templateUrl: 'sports/football.html'      
})
.state('sports.weightlifting', {
url: '/weightlifting', 
templateUrl: 'sports/weightlifting.html'      
})
.state('sports.swimming', {
url: '/swimming', 
templateUrl: 'sports/swimming.html'      
});
```

Basically, when a user opens the app, there should be top menu bar with Home, Sports and Country. When a user clicks Sports then there should be another view shown/ another sub navigation in this page showing Football, Weightlifting and Swimming. However these sub navigations are not clickable and not working.

It would be grateful if you can help me to find what would be the problem.

Comment: did you try this  --> ui-sref=".football"

Comment: do you have any console errors?

Comment: I believe you need a `)` after the path, so it should be something like `.state('home', {
url: '/', 
templateUrl: 'index.html'      
}).state('foo'...`

Comment: @salihşenolçakarcı, Yes I did try to do that however it didn't work that way as well.

Comment: @MannfromReno, Sorry, I forgot to put that when I was questioning. However now I have updated the question.

Comment: to detect problem , you may try to put "ui-sref" in another tag different then a tag

Comment: You're still missing closing parenthesis between `.state`

Comment: @salihşenolçakarcı, can you give me an example

Comment: your code looks like correct I suspect if "a" element triggering default href action . so try to use <div ui-sref="country">Country</div>

Comment: @MannfromReno, what I have learned is that, there should not be any closing parenthesis between .state

Comment: your question has the correct syntax, without the closing parenthesis you could not chain on `.state()`

Comment: See if this helps at all: http://jsfiddle.net/9a4qdqkh/

Comment: @MannfromReno, Okay, I will give a try, Thank you

Comment: @MannfromReno, Is it possible to create new html pages which will be children of sports.html that has three navigations in: jsfiddle.net/9a4qdqkh? So that I can test the pages.

Comment: Of course you can create child pages, I think you need to do a bit more research on angular routing and setting up these pages.

Comment: @MannfromReno, Sure I will. Thank you for your time. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue in your code. Probably you might be missing some dependencies.
Check out my plunker.[click here to view code demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/OfFwSA?p=preview)

app.js

```
(function(){

    angular
  .module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

  })();
```

router.js

```
(function(){

      'use strict';

      angular
      .module('plunker')
      .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider)
      {
          $stateProvider
          .state('home', {
                  url: '/', 
                templateUrl: 'home.html'      
                })
          .state('sports', {
          url: '/sports', 
          templateUrl: 'sports.html'      
          })    
            .state('sports.football', {
            url: '/football', 
            templateUrl: 'football.html'      
            })
            .state('sports.weightlifting', {
            url: '/weightlifting', 
            templateUrl: 'weightlifting.html'      
            })
            .state('sports.swimming', {
            url: '/swimming', 
            templateUrl: 'swimming.html'      
            })
          .state('country', {
          url: '/country', 
          templateUrl: 'country.html'      
          });

      }])


    })();
```

Comment: why do you have two angular configuration at the top? What does it do?
  .module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

  angular
  .module('plunker')
  .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider)

Comment: @JohnSmith: Sorry.. my bad. Thought of sperating the app js from routing using IIFE. but forgot it. Now I have updated my answer and plunker code as well. Cheers

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem of nested views. If you explicitly target the different views you can resolve it.

```
<ul> 
   <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a ui-sref="sports">Sports</a></li>
   <li><a ui-sref="country">Country</a></li>
</ul>
<div ui-view></div> <!-- your sports.html plugs in here -->
```

In sports.html :

```
<ul> 
   <li><a ui-sref="sports.football">Football</a></li>
   <li><a ui-sref="sports.weightlifting">Weightlifting</a></li>
   <li><a ui-sref="sports.swimming">Swimming</a></li>
</ul>
<div ui-view></div> <!-- your [sportName].html plugs in here -->
```

So in your app.js, you just have to add some params concerning the nested view in sport.html, like this :

```
$stateProvider
   .state('home', {
      url: '/', 
      templateUrl: 'index.html'      
   })
   .state('sports', {
      url: '/sports', 
      templateUrl: 'sports.html'      
   })    
   .state('country', {
      url: '/country', 
      templateUrl: 'country.html'      
   })
   .state('sports.football', {
      url: '/football',
      // Relatively targets the unnamed view in this state's parent state, 'sports'.
      // <div ui-view/> within sports.html
      views: {
         "": {
            templateUrl: 'sports/football.html'
         }
      }      
   })
   .state('sports.weightlifting', {
      url: '/weightlifting',
      // Relatively targets the unnamed view in this state's parent state, 'sports'.
      // <div ui-view/> within sports.html 
      views: {
         "": {
            templateUrl: 'sports/weightlifting.html'
         }
      } 
   })
   .state('sports.swimming', {
      url: '/swimming',
      // Relatively targets the unnamed view in this state's parent state, 'sports'.
      // <div ui-view/> within sports.html 
      views: {
         "": {
            templateUrl: 'sports/swimming.html'
         }
      } 
   });
```

If you want more details, you can read this doc : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-views

Comment: It seems like a good strategy. 
So, in the first one, shall I do <div ui-view="sports"></div> and second one three views, <div ui-vie="football"></div>, <div ui-view="weightlifting"></div> and <div ui-view="swimming"></div>

Comment: If you want to name every view you have to add more params in your $stateProvider configuration.

My solution allows you to avoid this. I take the swimming state example. The state _**sports.swimming**_ is explicitly considered like a child of the state _**sports**_. So, in the first `<ui-view>`, _sports.html_ (the parent state) is plugged and in the second `<ui-view>`, _sports/swimming.html_ (the child state) is plugged.

Comment: Okay. I will give a try. Thank you.

Comment: I am stil having the problem where the link are not even clickable.

Comment: Ah it's maybe due to another problem. Do you have a demo ?

Answer (score -1):

```
<li><a ng-click="goTo('sports.football')">Football</a></li>
```

In Your Controller

```
$scope.goTo = function(path){
 $state.go(path)
}
```

Comment: If you're using `ui-router` you should not need to implement an `ng-click` and a function in the controller.

Comment: Yes, you are right but to solve this problem I suggested a different way

Comment: @MannfromReno, Yes it would be easy if I can do it without the ng-click and controller. It would be great if I can twist something in my .state part of html part.